# Prove that $n^n>1\times3\times5\times7\times \dots\times(2n-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The main question is :

Prove that $n^n>1\times3\times5\times7\times\dots\times(2n-1)$

My approach :

We can write the R.H.S as, 
$$\frac{(2n-1)!}{2\times4\times6\times\dots\times2(n-1)}$$
We can write $(2n-1)!$ as $(2n-3)!(2n-1)2(n-1)$

Thus, in this manner we can cancel out even terms till $n$ appears. I'm having trouble doing this. What I intend to do is say that any positive number's factorial is less than the number raised to itself. I welcome any alternate method. Please help.

P.S. I am still in high school and do not understand binomial theorem and induction.

Comment: As you have not mentioned $n>1$ you must use $\geq$ sign instead of $>$ sign considering the $n=1$ case....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Using AM, GM inequality for $r,2n-r>0$ 
$$\dfrac{r+(2n-r)}2\ge\sqrt{r(2n-r)}$$

Set $r=1,3,5\cdots, 2n-3,2n-1$  and multiply.

Observe that the equality can not be held  as $r=2n-r$ will not occur unless $r=n$(which is again possible if  $n$ is odd)

Comment: I apply AM, GM for n terms?

Comment: @AksharGandhi, No for two terms,  $r,2n-r$  at  a time. Then multiply

Comment: Wow, A.M. G.M inequality is a very powerful tool. Thanks a lot lab sir.

Comment: This is quite efficient. +1

Answer (score 3):

Since $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$, your inequality is equivalent to
$$(2n)! < n! (2n)^n \tag{1}$$
or to:
$$ \underbrace{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+1)}_{n \text{ terms}}<\underbrace{(2n)\cdot(2n)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}_{n \text{ terms}}\tag{2} $$
that is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

For the first few cases this checks out, then assume it is true for $n$
$$n^n>(2n-1)!!$$

Then
$$(n+1)^{n+1}=\color{blue}{(n+1)^n (n+1)>2n^{n}(n+1)}=(2n-1)!!\times (2n+2)>(2n-1)!!\times (2n+1)>(2n+1)!!$$
Using the binomial theorem for the blue part:
$$(1+n)^n=n^n+n\times n^{n-1}+\binom n2 n^{n-2} +\cdots>2n^n$$

Comment: I am sorry, I have still not been taught this theorem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

We can induct on $n$. For $n=2$, it boils down to $4>3$. Now suppose it it true for $n=k$. Then we need to prove $k^k>(2k-1)!!\implies (k+1)^{k+1}>(2k+1)(2k-1)!!$

$$(k+1)^{k+1} =k^{k+1} +k\cdot k^k+ k(k-1)k^{k-1}/2 + \cdots > k^{k+1}+k\cdot k^k+(k^2-k)k^{k-1}/2=2.5k^{k+1} - 0.5k^k$$

by binomial theorem. Then $2.5k^{k+1}-0.5k^k = (k^k)(2.5k-0.5)>(2k-1)!!(2.5k-0.5)\geq(2k-1)!!(2k+1)= (2k+1)!!$

QED

Comment: I am sorry, I have still not been taught this theorem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by the double factorial sign?

Comment: Can you help me out to prove it by induction without using the binomial part?

Comment: @tatan Double facatorial example: 9!!=9.7.5.3.1, 10!!=10.8.6.4.2,11!!=11.9!!, 12!!=12.10!!,etc, where . is multiplication. As for proving it without the binomial theorem, you would have to establish the inequality that I stated with the binomial theorem, which is easiest using the binomial theorem, but (i think) can be proven in other ways (ex. derivatives(not tested))